# Record a Webcam video with python

Tags: python, opencv, wxpython

I am trying to capture a video from a webcam stream. The python logic is

> If button is pressed, store the current stream until I press the stop
>   button.

Note : I am using OpenCV to stream a webcam video inside a wxPython window.

```
  def record(self, evt):
      cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

      # Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
      fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
      out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
```

I have tried the above code but it only stores 5.54kb file in the output dirctory?

How to do it?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: No, I have tried none so far because I am new to python.

Comment: I'd say that your question is too broad. I recommend you to give it a try and come back with more specific problems that you'll face along the way. I wouldn't expect answers for these kind of questions here on SO.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll try by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have set up a video writer object by

`out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))`

but you have not used `write` method to write the video frame buffer.

To do it, you need to call `write` method of the writer object that you instantiated by:

```
success, buf = cap.read()
out.write(buf)
```

This has to be put in a loop or be called by `wx.Timer`, otherwise only one frame will be saved.

finally, when you are done with streaming, do `out.release()` to close the video file.